# CV Header lines showing out of order

Tags: overleaf, templates

I'm using the [FAANGPath](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/faangpath-simple-template/npsfpdqnxmbc) Resume template to build a resume, but I need to add an additional line for more websites.  In this template header, \ makes a diamond shape between items so I'm not sure how to make a newline without that command. I tried adding an additional \address{} line but then it is placed out of order in the header (right below the name rather than below the last line).

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}} 
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Your Name Here} % Your name
% You can merge both of these into a single line, if you do not have a website.
\address{999-999-9999 \\ City, CA} 
\address{\href{mailto:email@outlook.com}{email@outlook.com} \\ \href{https://linkedin.com/in/fist-last}{linkedin.com/in/fist-last} } 
\address{\href{https://researchgate.net/profile/fist-last}{researchgate.net/profile/fist-last} \\ \href{https://github.com/fist-last}{github.com/fist-last} }  %

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Now the `\\` will start a new line instead of inserting the diamond.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}} 
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}


\name{Firstname Lastname} % Your name
% You can merge both of these into a single line, if you do not have a website.
\address{+1(123) 456-7890 \\ San Francisco, CA} 

\address{\href{mailto:contact@faangpath.com}{contact@faangpath.com} \\ \href{https://linkedin.com/company/faangpath}{linkedin.com/company/faangpath} \\ 
    \href{www.faangpath.com}{www.faangpath.com}}  %


% *************************************added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\printaddress}[1]{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{center} #1\end{center}}
 \par
\addressskip
}
% *************************************


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{OBJECTIVE}
{Software Engineer with 2+ years of experience in XXX, seeking full-time XXX roles.}
\end{rSection}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}
{\bf Master of Computer Science}, Stanford University \hfill {Expected 2020}\\
Relevant Coursework: A, B, C, and D.

{\bf Bachelor of Computer Science}, Stanford University \hfill {2014 - 2017}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```